# certain sounds don't work after I start JACK

Tags: jack

I have ubuntu 12.10 on an acer aspire one 722 with ALSA & an ATI soundcard.
So, i finally figured out how to start JACK; I type in `jackd & qjackctl & jack_mixer` and then open a new terminal and open the applications i want to use JACK with, i.e. `zynaddsubfx & ardour2 & hydrogen`...This is the only way it will start JACK. I don't know why I need to open it with the mixer, but it's been working...

Maybe I need other JACK applications??? For all i know, these are the only three I have.

1.) If I use other applications before starting JACK, when i open qjackctl (or jackd & qjackctl) it says it doesn't recognize it:

```
13:09:14.967 Patchbay deactivated.
13:09:15.097 Statistics reset.
13:09:15.171 ALSA connection change.
13:09:15.795 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
13:09:16.461 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
13:09:16.486 ALSA connection graph change.
Sat Jan 26 13:09:15 2013: Starting jack server...
Sat Jan 26 13:09:15 2013: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: control device hw:0
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: control device hw:0
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: Acquired audio card Audio0
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: creating alsa driver ...   hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: control device hw:0
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: [1m[31mERROR: ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for    playback. Falling back to capture-only mode[0m
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Cannot initialize driver[0m
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: [1m[31mERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1[0m
Sat Jan 26 13:09:16 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to open server[0m
Sat Jan 26 13:09:17 2013: Saving settings to "/home/laura/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
13:09:19.882 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed.  - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

2.) When I run jackd, jack_mixer, and qjackctl as startup applications, they start up fine. And I can connect zynaddsubfx and ardour with them etc. But if I want to play a youtube video, no sound comes out, even if I quit JACK and then try to play it. It seems like starting JACK messes with the sound for my non-JACK applications.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: I was looking at tutorials on Utube and found the answer to your question. Here is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwThBGNh8HA. When you look at the video, make sure and look at the comment area. All of the Terminal information is there. Some of the information gets cut off in the actual video. Enjoy.

Comment: The video is unavailable. Does anyone know what the above commenter was referring to?